# Problems importing cx_oracle

Tags: python, gunicorn, supervisord, cx-oracle

I have a project in Python (running on Ubuntu 12.04) using cx_Oracle (inside a virtualenv). When I run the project I have no problems importing this module. Now I want to control my project using supervisor. When I start the project from supervisor, starting crashes and rises this exception:

```
File "/home/vagrant/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/vagrant/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/vagrant/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/vagrant/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/vagrant/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/vagrant/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/vagrant/scrapy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/vagrant/scrapy_server/flask_server/api.py", line 8, in <module>
    from resources.routes import routes
  File "/vagrant/scrapy_server/flask_server/resources/routes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from server.server import ServerStart, ServerStatus, ServerStop
  File "/vagrant/scrapy_server/flask_server/resources/server/server.py", line 8, in <module>
    from core.pool import ThreadPool
  File "/home/vagrant/scrapy/src/scrapy/scrapy_server/apps/core/pool.py", line 7, in <module>
    from resources.resources import Resources
  File "/vagrant/scrapy_server/flask_server/resources/resources.py", line 10, in <module>
    from repository.HotTypes import HotTypes
  File "/vagrant/scrapy_server/flask_server/resources/repository/HotTypes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from db_pg import DBPostgres
  File "/vagrant/scrapy_server/flask_server/resources/repository/db_pg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from resources.db_pg import DBPostgres as DBpostgresResources
  File "/vagrant/scrapy_server/flask_server/resources/db_pg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from core.dbcore import DBpostgresCore
  File "/home/vagrant/scrapy/src/scrapy/scrapy_server/apps/core/dbcore.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
ImportError: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I followed instructions from [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client#Install_RPMs) site and also [this other](https://gist.github.com/kimus/10012910) site. But I was not able to fix this problem.

The supervisor conf file is:

```
[program:api_server]
command = /home/vagrant/scrapy/bin/gunicorn api:app
directory = /home/vagrant/scrapy/src/scrapy/scrapy_server/flask_server/
environment = PATH="/home/vagrant/scrapy/bin/python", ORACLE_HOME="/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64", LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib"
user = vagrant
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/api.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/api.out.log
redirect_stderr = True
```

What am I missing here? If you need more info just let me know and I will update this question.

Thank you all

Comment: Did you set all required env variables (like $ORACLE_HOME, ...) ?

Comment: yes, as I wrote, I set all enviroments varibles required as explained in a tutorial (link is above). The project runs perfectly if I start it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Oracle Instant Client, do not set the environment variable ORACLE_HOME. The only thing you need to set is LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the location of libclntsh.so.

From your environment variables you are using an Oracle Instant Client with version 12.1 but cx_Oracle itself appears to be compiled with 11.2. That will need to be corrected. You need to make sure that cx_Oracle is compiled with 12.1 or you need to use the new cx_Oracle 6.0b1 which automatically switches between different Oracle client versions automatically.

Comment: Indeed was about using 12.1 instead of 11.2 (Duh, I overlooked it). I will test Oracle without setting ORACLE_HOME as you suggested. Thanks for your help!